# Long-press enter as Control key

Tags: 14.04, emacs

I am a Emacs user and I want to have Long-press enter as an extra control key. I used to do this in Mac OS with KeyboardRemap4Macbook. But was not able to find it how to do in Ubuntu Unity. This would greatly save my left finger :)

Answer (score 1):

This got solved by using xcape (`sudo apt-get install xcape` or from github - https://github.com/alols/xcape)

and following the script in the README:

```
# Map an unused modifier's keysym to the spacebar's keycode and make it a
# control modifier. It needs to be an existing key so that emacs won't
# spazz out when you press it. Hyper_L is a good candidate.
spare_modifier="Hyper_L"
xmodmap -e "keycode 65 = $spare_modifier"
xmodmap -e "remove mod4 = $spare_modifier" # hyper_l is mod4 by default
xmodmap -e "add Control = $spare_modifier"

# Map space to an unused keycode (to keep it around for xcape to
# use).
xmodmap -e "keycode any = space"

# Finally use xcape to cause the space bar to generate a space when tapped.
xcape -e "$spare_modifier=space"
```

This has worked for me irrespective of the distro - I have got it working on Fedora 23 and Debian9 as well other than Ubuntu 17.04 as it is a generic solution. Thanks